# Ассемблер: как получить код символа?

Tags: ассемблер, linux

Допустим, есть строка `string db "GOODBYE",0xa`. Мне нужен первый символ этой строки. Насколько я понимаю, достаточно сделать так:

```
mov eax,[string]
```

Чтобы получить содержимое первого элемента массива (первый символ), если верить таблице ASCII (и UTF-8), то код символа должен быть 47. Вместо этого я получаю число 542393671.

Если выполнить:

```
mov dword [buf],542393671
```

и вывести строку, то выяснится, что это действительно код буквы G, а число 47 - код символа '/'.

```
mov dword [buf],542393671        ;результат: GOODBYE
;mov dword [buf],47              ;результат: /OODBYE

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,string
mov edx,len
int 0x80
```

Собственно вопрос: почему содержимое памяти не соответствует таблице ASCII?

OS: Ubuntu

компилятор: NASM

Comment: 47h (шестнадцатиричная запись) — код символа G, а 47 (десятичная запись) — символа /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Командой `mov eax,[string]` вы берете не один байт (первый символ), а сразу 4, т.к. регистр eax - четырехбайтовый.

Вам нужно загружать символ либо в однобайтовый регистр:

```
mov al, [string]
```

либо загружать в eax один байт с добиванием остальных байтов нулями командой movzx (ZX - zero extension, еще бывает movsx - sign extension, т.е. считается, что загружается знаковое число и "лишние" байты заполняются значением бита знака), указывая при этом, что мы читаем только один байт (в ascii 1 символ занимает 1 байт):

```
movzx eax, byte [string]
```

Не представляю, как вы командой `mov dword [buf],47` заменяете только первый символ, т.к. должно записаться 4 байта (dword), в 16-ричном виде 0000002Fh. В буфере это будет выглядеть как 2F 00 00 00 (+ оставшиеся байты строки), и на экран должно вывестись только '/': http://ideone.com/Q6C1mn .

Если требуется заменить только один символ, нужно писать `mov byte [buf], 47`:
http://ideone.com/hXQ5bx

Как уже заметил [[@Дож](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6), 47 - это код символа '/', а 47h - код символа 'G'.

И еще одно: команда `mov dword [buf],542393671` не может дать результат 'GOODBYE', она даст результат 'GET ', во-первых, потому что это совершенно не те коды символов (кроме первого), во-вторых, командой mov в 32-битном режиме вы можете записать максимум 4 байта (а командой mov dword - **ровно** 4 байта), а в слове 'GOODBYE' их целых 7.